# WPF finish button animation before perform click

Tags: wpf, animation, button, click

I have button with a coloranimation, and a click event. The coloranimation animates the background of the button from gray to orange in 1 seconds, then reverse it. In the click event I load a lot of things (it takes around 4-5 secs).

My problem is that, when I click on the button the animation begins, but immediately stops after a few millisecs(click event started), and after the click event finished, it finishes the animation as well. 
I want that first finish the animation, then executes click event.

I googled a lot, and found the animation completed event and it's working, but is it possible somehow to make a basic solution for this, that I can use for all of my buttons in my program?

Thanks for the replies in advance!

BR,
Zoli

EDIT: ---------------------------------------------

Do something like this:

```
PreviewMouseDown()
{
    AnimateTheButton();
    //Wait for the animation to be finished
}
```

Comment: See [VisualStateManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.visualstatemanager.aspx) class and its [usage for button](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753328.aspx)

Comment: Oh, sorry, I misunderstood the problem. Then maybe you could disable animation when PreviewMouseUp event fired?

Comment: I don't want to disable :) . I would like to first animate the button, then execute the click event :) .
Now it starts the animate, but immediately start the methods in the click event, and stops the animation, what is the problem :( .

Comment: Oh, that`s the trouble :) Each animation provides [Completed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.timeline.completed.aspx) event. Move your handler there

Comment: Yeah, completed event works well :) , but I want a basic solution, so I know only that, I have to call the click event of the button after the animation, but I don't more in the high level class.

I tried to do something like that:

PreviewMouseDown()
{
   AnimateTheButton();
}

ButtonClickEvent()
{
  //Wait for the animation to be finished
  //Do what the button have to do :)
}

Comment: In this comment I can't create newline, so I edited my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, if you want beautiful and reusable solution check out what I wrote for you.
Just add this class into your solution.

```
public sealed class AnimatedButton : Button
{
    private bool _isAnimationRunning;

    public static readonly DependencyProperty AnimationProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Animation", typeof(Storyboard), typeof(AnimatedButton));

    public Storyboard Animation
    {
        get { return (Storyboard) GetValue(AnimationProperty); }
        set { SetValue(AnimationProperty, value); }
    }

    protected override void OnPreviewMouseDown(System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        _isAnimationRunning = true;
        if (Animation != null)
        {
            var clonedAnimation = Animation.Clone(); // Else we cannot subscribe Completed event
            clonedAnimation.Completed += OnAnimationComplete;
            clonedAnimation.Begin(this);
        }
        base.OnPreviewMouseDown(e);
    }

    protected override void OnClick()
    {
        if (Animation != null && _isAnimationRunning)
        {
            return;
        }
        base.OnClick();
    }

    private void OnAnimationComplete(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        _isAnimationRunning = false;
        OnClick();
    }
}
```

Usage. Just insert it into application resources:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="{x:Type controls:AnimatedButton}" TargetType="{x:Type TestWpf:AnimatedButton}">
        <Setter Property="Animation">
            <Setter.Value>
                <Storyboard Duration="0:0:2">
                    <DoubleAnimation From="0.2" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity">
                    </DoubleAnimation>
                </Storyboard>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

And then you can use it like the usual button:

```
<local:AnimatedButton Click="OnAnimatedButtonClicked">
    Super cool button
</local:AnimatedButton>
```

Comment: Yeah, this is the answer, I was waiting for :) .

I thought about to create an own button class as well, but I hoped that maybe there is an easier solution.

Thanks for your answer! :)